# How can I handle Castor unmarshaling of SOAP messages when the namespace is defined inside the operation tag?

Tags: java, web-services, spring-ws, castor, unmarshalling

I am developing a contract-first web service based on Spring-WS. I'm relying on Castor marshaling, and I have run into the following issue.

Requests are being accepted when the "xmlns" namespace is defined in the Envelope tag, such as:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                      xmlns="http://www.mycompany.com/MyService/schemas">
  <soap:Header/>
  <soap:Body>
    <doPlaceHoldRequest>
      <hold>
        <accountInfo>
          <accountNumber>123456789</accountNumber>
        </accountInfo>
        <extended>false</extended>
        <afterHours>false</afterHours>
        <amountSavings>1.00</amountSavings>
        <amountChecking>0.00</amountChecking>
      </hold>
    </doPlaceHoldRequest>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

However, both .NET and Java clients generated from the .wsdl provided by Spring-WS (which was generated from a XSD), form their requests in the following manner:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header/>
  <soap:Body>
    <doPlaceHoldRequest 
                xmlns="http://www.mycompany.com/MyService/schemas">
      <hold>
        <accountInfo>
          <accountNumber>123456789</accountNumber>
        </accountInfo>
        <extended>false</extended>
        <afterHours>false</afterHours>
        <amountSavings>1.00</amountSavings>
        <amountChecking>0.00</amountChecking>
      </hold>
    </doPlaceHoldRequest>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Which results in an Unmarshalling Exception being thrown by Castor. How do I get Castor to recognize these messages as valid? Could my WSDL (or the XSD I used to autogenerate it) be wrong?

Comment: So far I've switched to plain old Jax-WS and it is working like a charm. Never again I will touch Spring-WS and Castor... such a headache!

Comment: Those two XML documents are semantically identical, despite the difference in the namespace declaration positions. If Castor doesn't like one of them but likes the other, then Castor is broken. Spring-WS is the best option, in my experience, JAX-WS is too clunky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF u see this blog i think will never go to other webservices :) 
http://springkbase.blogspot.com/2009/06/spring-webservice-with-castor.html

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this problem over and over again with my first Spring-WS/Castor web service. As far as I can tell, somewhere along the line some component extracts the payload in a non-namespace-aware way. In other words, a node like doPlaceHoldRequest becomes the root of an XML document without inheriting the top-level namespace declaration, and in the two cases above, that leads to one that *is* in the namespace you want, and one that is not - so one validates fine against your schema, and the other does not.

The best solution seems to be to cover all the bases. Make your XSD have elementFormDefault="qualified", to require all your elements to be in a namespace. Then specify an ns-uri and an ns-prefix in every map-to element in your Castor mapping. The result is a little heavier, with all the namespace prefixes, but it seems to make it a lot less fragile when it comes to lazy clients *and* undocumented behavior in server components.

[JAX-WS return empty lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601113/jax-ws-return-empty-lists/3602475#3602475) makes a good point, too. `org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.interceptor.PayloadValidatingInterceptor` is worth having to validate what comes in and out.